# hexedit: change number of columns (bytes per line)

Tags: dd, mbr, hexdump, hex

I am using `hexedit` to show/edit disk MBR (512 Bytes, copied with dd).

When I open the file, `hexedit` displays the file as 9 columns, 4 bytes
per column (36 bytes per line). That is very unfortunate. I need to have
it aligned in a meaningful way (ie 8 columns, 32 columns per line)

I could not find any way to do it in the manual page.

Is there  a trick I could use ?

## UPDATE:

here are the commands I use:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.img bs=512 count=1
hexedit sda.img
```

regarding the output I get, it looks similar to slm's, only with 9 columns instead of 8.

Comment: Can you please include the commands you actually used? Showing the output you're getting and the output you want would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it keys off of the width of your terminal. If you size the terminal just right you can get `hexedit` to show you 8 columns instead of 9.

#### Example

```
00000000   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000020   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000040   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000060   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000080   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
000000A0   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
000000C0   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
000000E0   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000100   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000120   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000140   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000160   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
00000180   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
000001A0   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ................................
000001C0   01 00 EE FE  FF FF 01 00  00 00 AF 32  CF 1D 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ...........2....................
000001E0   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 55 AA  ..............................U.
00000200
00000220
00000240
00000260
00000280
```

I had the column width of the above terminal set to 151x55.

```
$ resize
COLUMNS=151;
LINES=55;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```